# Production Push Notifications using Firebase with APNs Auth Key

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, production

When testing my application on TestFlight I have noticed that I do not receive push notifications.

I have confirmed that I can receive notifications initiated from both cloud functions and the firebase console when loading builds from Xcode.

I have referenced other similar questions but none of them reflect the precise problem I am dealing with. When configuring for remote notifications in Firebase I am using an **APNs Auth Key**, I have also included both `.p12` files for Development and Production. However, the `.p12` files are greyed out and listed as inactive because the APNs Auth Key has been setup.

On my Apple Developer account under **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**, I have made sure that my APNs Auth Key exists in the left **Keys** section. I have also setup **Developer and Production SSL Certificates** in my App Id & verified that they are listed as "enabled". I have also verified that I have an iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile that is "active".

This is a difficult problem to debug because Xcode builds work yet TestFlight builds do not. I know this issue deals with production vs. development environments but I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

This method is being called in Xcode builds and all associated `UserNotifications` & `Messaging` delegate methods are being called. I am running iOS 10.3 & have `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` set to `NO` in my `info.plist`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
     Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
     Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod)
}
```

Comment: Did u find any answer? I am facing exact same issue.

Comment: I'll go in and check my code tomorrow then post the solution. This was from an old project & I know I figured it out later on.

Comment: @EliWhittle did you find what the solution was?

Comment: Did anyone found any solution for this issue? I am facing this issue right now. I want to use APNS auth key but not able to get APNS in the production build.

Answer (score 2):

The fix for me was to stop using MessagingAPNSTokenType.sandbox or .prod, and just use:

```
Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
```

In a previous app, I used:

```
if Config.isDebug {
    tokenType = MessagingAPNSTokenType.sandbox
} else {
    tokenType = MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod
}
Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: tokenType)
```

and set up Config to depend on the build scheme in Xcode. Now it appears not to work in prod. On Firebase, I am now using an [APNS Key](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token_based_connection_to_apns), as opposed to the older style Prod and Dev certificates. That may have made a difference. I see that the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Enums/MessagingAPNSTokenType) also now say:

> If the token type is set to UNKNOWN Firebase Messaging will implicitly
>   try to figure out what the actual token type is from the provisioning
>   profile. Unless you really need to specify the type, you should use
>   the APNSToken property instead.

Comment: I am using the nodejs lib for sending message, not sure how to set this token type https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your info.plist a support for push notifications in the background mode.
[image]

You can do this also by adding a new capability under the Signing & Capabilites tab in your target settings.

[image]