# APNs Authentication Key Fails for Production in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, provisioning-profile

I've been using my APNs Authentication Key successfully for my app while it's been in development. Been receiving push notifications well, and all indented behavior has been there.

However, for production (testflight) all notifications have been failing. I've been struggling to understand why, and assumed I was signing / configuring something on the client incorrectly (I made sure to use `Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)` however).

In my desperate groping at straws, I've changed my Firebase configuration to use APNS Certs instead, and, for reasons beyond me, my push notifications have begun working in my production environment.

I'm relatively new to APNs Auth Keys instead of certs, so I assume I'm missing something, but, since these suckers are supposed to be good for a whole developer account (right?) I'm at a complete loss as to what.

Answer (score 6):

There is some error using Authentication Key because I have the same issue. After change APNs Authentication Key and use traditional APNs certificates all notifications works again.

Maybe this answer solve your problem:
[Production Push Notifications using Firebase with APNs Auth Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446527/production-push-notifications-using-firebase-with-apns-auth-key?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have included your push notification entitlement in release and debug build.
I've spent a half of day before I found out this mistake. Thank you Apple.
[image]

Comment: shouldnt all change for both?

Comment: It appears that way for "All" if you have it set for both Debug and Release @stefan

Answer (score 0):

when it is on TestFlight or local dev, it is talk to apple dev push servers, where we need to convert the apns token into registration token. As long as APNS key is used, which is the new solution, if it is local dev or TestFlight, it does not matter.

[image]

I have wasted 2 hours when firebase keeps saying not able to send message, it is because I need to turn the sandbox boolean to false while I am working with the app downloaded from TestFlight.....